# ¿Cómo poner un Fragment dentro de otro fragment?

Tags: java, android, menú, layout

Buenas, tengo lo siguiente que sí que funciona, y me muestra 4 pestañas y hago click y me sale lo que sale en los respectivos layouts, que es un simple textview.

Mi MainActivity:

---

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


   private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     tabHost= (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
     tabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("1º"),
                           Tab1.class, null);
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("2º"),
                           Tab2.class, null);
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("3º"),
                           Tab3.class, null);
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("4º"),
                           Tab4.class, null);
    }
}
```

---

Y muestro por ejemplo una de las 4 pestañas que tengo, ( las otras 3 no las muestro pues son copiar-pegar) :

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }



    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);

    }

}
```

El problema es que quiero que una vez pulse una pestaña de las 4 que tengo creadas, me cree exactamente lo mismo justo bajo, pero con dos pestañas, en vez del textview que tengo,quiero como un submenú.

Cuando pulse "pestaña1", que bajo me aparezcan 2 pestañas más pudiendo elegir una de ellas y que me lleve a mi activity no sé si me explico. He intentado copiar-pegar código del MainActivity que sí funcionaba a mi primera pestaña.java y .xml pero nada, sin resultado... Se ralla.

Comment: Lo que me refiero es un subFragment, por así decirlo, que me aparezcan otras pestañas debajo.

Comment: Hola no tienes una imagen de lo que deseas realizar?

Comment: No sé como subir una imagen... pero lo que me refiero son 3 pestañas arriba , las de toda la vida , pinchas en una de ellas y te muestra lo que hay en esa pestaña, dependiendo que pestaña pulses aparece una cosa. Pues buen, yo quiero que al pinchar una pestaña, en vez de aparecerme cualquier cosa como un boton o un textview... me salga de nueva 2 pestañas más debajo, manteniendo las que estaban antes arriba...